# How to design a main list and sublists schema

Tags: entity-framework, database-design, ef-code-first

I am finding it difficult to design a database schema for a list feature. there would be a master list which then can be subsectioned into further lists.

each user is able to mark a candidate as a favourite candidate and can have many favourite candidates.

if a candidate is deleted from a list then it should still remain part of favourites, or be part of the main favoirtes list without belonging to a particular list.

- a user can mark many candidates as favourite
- a user can have many favourites lists
- a favourites list can have many candidates
  the following is what I have come up with so far.
  [image]

as shown in the above image I am allowing the FavouritesListId to be nullable, this way if a list item is not associated with a certain list this means it is still favourited but not part of a particular list.
I want to know if this is the optimal solution or if there is a better design approach available.

I am guessing there is something wrong with my design because when I use Entity framework to map my tables it ends up with a circular dependency as shown below:

```
public partial class Model1 : DbContext
    {
        public Model1()
            : base("name=Model1")
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Candidate> Candidates { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<FavouritesList> FavouritesLists { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<FavouritesListItem> FavouritesListItems { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Candidate>()
                .HasMany(e => e.FavouritesListItems)
                .WithRequired(e => e.Candidate)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasMany(e => e.FavouritesListItems)
                .WithRequired(e => e.User)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }
    }
```

as shown in the above code the candidates end up having many favouriesLisItems which is not my intention.